# how see left or right sidebar in search result page?

Tags: search

I'm sorry if it sounds like obvious question, but I cannot solve this... I'm using D7.15, customized Fusion subtheme and Display Suite to style the search result appearance. But all the times I get the search results page in fullscreen (no left or right sidebars) and I can't find the solution for this. No costomizations on search-results.tpl.php.

please help! :/

UPDATE: I'm using drupal core search, I have tried Search by page module too.

Comment: Enable some blocks on right side or left side region... Then you can able to see them...

Comment: What do you mean by "enable"? If you are talking about telling some particular block to appear on the left/right sidebar so of course I have tried it. Not working - looks like it forces to disable block regions (like an option in Display Suite), but the problem is that I cannot control it, or at least I don't know where to do that.

Comment: Do you by any chance have additional page--*.tpl.php files that might be matching for the search page? Are you certain the blocks that you want to display in these regions aren't empty on the search page?

Comment: No, I have non page--*tpl.php files, so there is nothing from that part that could override behaviour of columns. And the blocks - I am testing with normal working blocks, like "seach" block, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Create one template file: **page--search.tpl.php**.

Write the following code:

```
//to print the main content
print render($page['content']);

//to print your right side-bar
print render($page['name_of_the_region_with_right_sidebar']);
```

and other customization as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you,

As I understand, you need to show right and left sidebar in the search page.
You can achieve it using [**context**](https://drupal.org/project/context) module.

Steps

- After enabling the context module, add a new context using **admin/structure/context/add**

  [image]
- Select **PATH condition**

  [image]
- **Add search PATH**

  [image]
- Now its time to add blocks, **select Block Reactions**

  [image]
- Now add the your blocks in right and left sidebars.

  - **Select blocks**

    [image]
  - **After adding the blocks**

    [image]
- **Search result with blocks**

  [image]

NOTE

- Follow the same steps for **search/user/***

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be possible with the default core Search module or even [apachesolr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr).